# Проблема с медиазапросами

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, bootstrap

Допустим у нас есть блок `div`

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-1">
            <div class="test></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-1">
            <div class="test></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-1">
            <div class="test></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Проблема состоит в том что при расширении `600px` срабатывает `col-xs-1`, смотря на медиазапрос `xs` должен работать до `480px`, при `600` должна работать `sm` колонка!

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Система `col-xs` рассчитана на разрешение менее `768px` 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid, а сетка `sm` рассчитана на разрешение от `768px` до `992px`

Comment: Получаеться что сетку изменили ?Как должны сейчас выгледеть медиа запросы?

Comment: по ссылке как раз переход на сетку:  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid - .col-xs- Extra small devices Phones (<768px); .col-sm-  Small devices Tablets (≥768px); .col-md-  Medium devices Desktops (≥992px);  .col-lg-   Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)